# convert array to word

Tags: php, arrays

i have converted a word as per requirement to an **array**, done some **functions** and now again i want to convert it back to a **word**. when i add a break on the *echo*, i see it still acts as an array.

```
$word='someword';   
$arr= str_split($word);
foreach ($arr as $value) 
echo   $words =chr(ord($value)+2).'<br>';
```

The result of above is

```
u q o g y q t f
```

i did a function to check whether my requirement is met.

***failed***

Please help, i have tried ***implode*, *merge*, *join***

```
if($words!='uqogyqtf'){
 echo 'failed';
}else{
 echo 'Okay';
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem now?

Comment: I want a single word like $new_word='newword'; , now it is array(n,e,w,w,o,r,d);

Comment: in your original code $words will actually only be the last character which is "f<br>". what you actually want is `$words[] = chr(ord($value)+2);`

Comment: please  edit your question with exact output also.

Comment: @Aarvee Thapa what output you expect for above code/

Comment: @user     you can check my if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the line-break in your code and concatenate the variable and it should work fine.

```
$word='someword';   
$arr= str_split($word);
$words = '';
foreach ($arr as $value) 
     $words .=chr(ord($value)+2);
echo $words;
if($words!='uqogyqtf'){
    echo 'failed';
}else{
    echo 'Okay';
}
```

Ouput(take out `echo $words;` to only have "Okay"):

> uqogyqtfOkay

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be:

```
$word='someword';   
$arr= str_split($word);
$words = [];
foreach ($arr as $value) {
       $words[] =chr(ord($value)+2);
}
echo implode('', $words);
```

In your code at some point `$words` contained only on character at a time, not keeping the previous values.

Comment: have you tried the what you have pasted here...it gives error

Comment: Array declaration is wrong. Also don't need array, `$words = '';
foreach ($arr as $value) {
       $words .=chr(ord($value)+2);
}
echo $words;`

Comment: As of PHP 5.4 you can use the short notation for declaring an array.. []

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertword($word)
{ $myarray = str_split($word);
  foreach ($myarray as $key => $value)
  { $mynewarray[$key] = chr(ord($myarray[$key])+2);
  }
  $newword = implode("", $mynewarray);
  return $newword;
}
```

This works for me :)

Comment: Then just rename it, hm? But you are right, I just had no problem with that because I called it inside of model.
Edited the name in my code.